# How to ask for someone’s time?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, phrases, questions, spoken-english

How to ask someone you know for their time for setting up a phone call or meeting, to talk about something important in a productive and focused way. Like you are asking your manager in a formal way?

Comment: Do you mean ‘how to ask when they’re available’?

Comment: Yes, their availability for discussing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you can say this. It also depends on the relationship between you and the person you are trying to set up a meeting with.

I am going to assume you are asking this by email. Perhaps the two most important things to mention in your email are *the reason you are requesting a meeting* and *the time (and place) you are available*.

---

Here is an example. Note that these are just my words that I came up with now; I may or may not use them when I am about to send an email. The takeaway from this should be "what are the things I need to include in the email".

> Hello Count,

You can use any salutation that is appropriate for the relationship between the two of you (you said you know this person). If I am emailing one of my professors at the university, I would go with *"Hi Dr. Dracula,"* or *"Good evening Dr. Dracula,"*.

> Hope you are well.

This is optional. Some might advise against it. I personally like to use something like that if I care about the person.

> I was wondering if you have some time to meet this week. I would like to discuss (or talk about) ...

**Clearly state the reason you want to meet.**

If possible, be specific. *"I have something to say"* and *"I needed to talk about something"* does not work. You don't have to be too specific though.

- Try not to be vague: "I would like to talk about my paper." ❌
- Try not to be too specific: "I would like to talk about the two-stage least squares regression equations and the negative and statistically insignificant coefficient of the daylight variable." ❌
- This is fine: "I would like to talk about some problems I am facing in my data analysis section." ✅

> I am available from 5:30 a.m. to 5:30 p.m. on Monday and Wednesday, and from ... on Thursday and Friday. I can meet you in your dungeon if you would like, or we can meet in the computer lab.
>
> If you are not available during these times, or if you wish to meet elsewhere, please suggest what works best for you.

**Let them know when you are available.**

This is very important. Be flexible when you tell them about your availability. And remember to ask them for their preference. If you are always available at a particular time, then it should be "Monday**s** and Wednesday**s**" and so on.

If there are arrangements you need to make for the meeting, then you can ask them for a reply or confirmation (so that you have enough time to get things done).

---

Here are some options for asking if they are available to meet:

> *I was (or am) wondering if you are available to meet next week.* Basically what I discussed above.
>
> *I would like to talk about ... (state the reason). Are you available to meet tomorrow (or any specific day) from ... (mention time).*
>
> *I would like to talk about ... (state the reason). Is there a time (and place) we can meet next week?* This is if *you* are available to meet anytime.